# Using sf package for R to calculate distances for large dataset of location pairs

Tags: r, sf, large-datasets, st-distance

Working with data set of about 84k location pairs and trying to run in same manner as example code below. Getting results where distances are returned in an object of n x n dimension so when run on full data set compute isn't really possible on local device.

Looking for alternatives or changes to the methods below for efficiently calculating distances between large set of location pairs.

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  lat = c(40:44),
  long = c(80:84)
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  lat = c(35:39),
  long = c(75:79)
)
  
df_1
df_2

df_1_sf <- st_as_sf(df_1, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)
df_2_sf <- st_as_sf(df_2, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)

distances <- st_distance(df_1_sf, df_2_sf)

distance_df <- data.frame(distances)
distance_df
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the RANN library (Approximate Near Neighbor (ANN) C++ library). I have had luck with processing large data very fast using `RANN::nn2`. Unfortunately, you do not have the advantage of correcting for spherical geometry or outputting in meters as `sf:st_distance` does so, output will be in decimal degrees. I would assert that for the most part, distance based analysis should be conducted in a projected coordinate system anyway.

```
library(RANN)
library(sf)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:5),
  lat = c(40:44), long = c(80:84))
df1 <- sf::st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1:5),
  lat = c(35:39),long = c(75:79))
df2 <- sf::st_as_sf(df2, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)

sf::st_distance(df1, df2)
RANN::nn2(sf::st_coordinates(df1), 
          sf::st_coordinates(df2), 
          k = nrow(df1))$dist
```

If you benchmark this with just n=1000 observations you will note a significant difference in processing time. With an increase to n=10,000 `sf::st_distance` scales in a very undesirable way (eg., with n=1000 and n=10000 being 2.6 verses 277 elapsed cpu) whereas RANN:nn2 demonstrates a more efficient increase (0.11 verses 52 elapsed cpu).

```
n=1000
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:n),
  lat = runif(n, 40, 44), long = runif(n, 80, 84))
df1 <- sf::st_as_sf(df1, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1:n),
  lat = runif(n, 35, 39),long = runif(n, 75, 79))
df2 <- sf::st_as_sf(df2, coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4269)

system.time({ sfd <- sf::st_distance(df1, df2) })
system.time({ nnd <- nn2(sf::st_coordinates(df1), 
                         sf::st_coordinates(df2), 
                         k = nrow(df1))$dist })
```